# using $nearSphere + limit in a mongodb find query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb, pymongo-2.x

I've created a query with `$nearSphere` and I realized that I get sometimes **enormous** amount of results (1000+), which affects my app's performance.

I've tried to use `.limit()` but it seems to be ignored by the query.
I also tried to use `batch_size()` and it doesn't seem to affect the number of the results returned at all.

Is there any kind of hack or a way to limit the results returned?
I thought about execution with an iterator, this is what I've and it doesn't seem great for performance:

```
for r in xrange(0,limit):
        print res.next()
```

The query itself is quite simple:

```
query = {"location": {
    "$nearSphere": {"$geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates"
     [geo['lat'], geo['lng']]}, "$maxDistance": 500}}}


coll.find(query).limit(4).batch_size(4)
```

I'm using the Mongodb API on Azure Cosmos-db

Answer (score 1):

I cannot repro this issue. Limit works just fine. Try to use the example doc (make few copies of it in the same collection) from https://aka.ms/mongodb-feature-support and the query from the docs and append .limit(1) to it to see the correct behavior:

db.volcanos.find({ "Location.coordinates": { $nearSphere : { $geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [ -121, 46 ]}, $minDistance: 1000, $maxDistance: 1000000 } } }).limit(1)

Comment: Very strange, i'm using almost the same query and i can see limit is being ignored.
The location property on my db looks like that: `  "location": {
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates": [
    34.780659466136484,
    32.08260571073972
   ]
  }` maybe it is a format issue?

Comment: It also might be related to the fact my query is on "location" and not "location.coordinates"? I get 0 results on "location.coordinates"

Comment: play around with minDistance and maxDistance values - you might not be getting an overlap with the shape they're defining.